# GetCloseMatches R function returns list() for few cases while string matching. Any Idea?

Tags: r, list, output

Guy,

I am fairly new to R and trying to do a fuzzy string match. I am using FuzzyWuzzyR library, specifically the `GetCloseMatches` function.

Everything is fine except that in few cases the function returns `list()` as an output. Do you have any idea bout it?

Eg. if you execute this

```
GetCloseMatches("laZ", c("1 lazy", "1", "1 LAZY"),1L,0.7)
```

It returns `List()`

Please help.

Thanks,
Anuj

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: That means it is returning an empty list. If you adjust the cutoff to 0.4 or less, it returns "lazy". I haven't looked enough into the cutoff calculation, but the documentation may show more. `?GetCloseMatches` shows two references.

Comment: Hey thanks but is there a way to keep cutoff high and get rid of the list

Comment: @Anuj, the fuzzywuzzyR package ports the 'fuzzywuzzy' and 'difflib' python packages in R. For your specific question (on how to adjust the parameters) you can find more details (besides the ones in the [R package](https://rdrr.io/cran/fuzzywuzzyR/man/GetCloseMatches.html)) either in the [python 'difflib' package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) or in the ['Difflib.js' package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/difflib#getCloseMatches).

Comment: I was thinking if we can apply any if or case function on the statement and return a single value in case it returns list(). Is this possible?